# How does the compare function in std::map in C++ work if it is reflexively true?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I have a map in my project.
Every time I insert a new element, I want to ensure that the key of the new element I insert is at least a minimum width apart from other elements in the map. To do this I wrote a custom compare class like this:

```
class PulseCompare
{
public:
    PulseCompare(int minwidth_):minwidth(minwidth_){};
    bool operator()(const int x, const int y) const {
        if(abs(x-y)>minwidth) return false;
        else return true;
    }
private:
    int minwidth;
};
```

and created the map like this:

```
std::map<int,float,PulseCompare> pulsemap(PulseCompare(256));
```

and before I insert an element I use the `map.find` method like this:

```
if ( pulsemap.find(1600) == pulsemap.end() ) {
  // not found so I can insert
} else {
  // found
}
```

But the problem is that when map tries to reflexively compare using the above compare function by interchanging the values of `x` and `y`, it would get a `true` for both the cases which is usually not the case with normal comparison operators like `<` and `>`

On the cplusplus documentation page on `std::map::key_comp` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/key_comp/) it says and I quote

> The comparison object of a map object is set on construction. Its type (member key_compare) is the third template parameter of the map template. By default, this is a less object, which returns the same as operator "<".
>
> This object determines the order of the elements in the container: it is a function pointer or a function object that takes two arguments of the same type as the element keys, and returns true if the first argument is considered to go before the second in the strict weak ordering it defines, and false otherwise.
>
> Two keys are considered equivalent if key_comp returns false reflexively (i.e., no matter the order in which the keys are passed as arguments).

But this does not say about a case where it is reflexively `true`. Can anyone tell me what will be its behaviour then? Or should I do this interval comparison only by iterating over the entire map?

Comment: you want to know what happens if a>b and b>a... god I hope the universe isn't broken

Comment: I'm not sure how even `std::map<int,float> pulsemap(PulseCompare(256));` is [working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28652fff9a9ccde0)

Comment: @P0W you can pass the object of compare as a constructor arguement

Comment: @VivekVK Could you please tell it how with exactly your example here, (share the link) I've never used that.

Comment: @POW terribly sorry. just Realised there was a typo there. I had to give the compare class in the template before I pass it through the argument. I have edited it now. I guess now it makes things clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use this as your comparator?

```
return minwidth < (y - x);
```

Here is a working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e115d3a2f6714773

Comment: Consider I have 1700 already in it and I am inserting 1600, 1800.having min width of 256 I should say 1600-1700 <256 and 1800-1700<256 that is why I need abs()

Comment: Your comparison will be run twice to check for equality (once from each side).  abs is not needed.  Have [you tried it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e115d3a2f6714773)?

Comment: I am not telling about swapping x and y in my comparator. I want the inserting element not to be in present element plus or minus the minwidth. and I need abs() to check both the sides of the present element. Am I making sense? or still am I wrong and not understanding it?

Comment: You are still not understanding.  The comparison function is essentially a "less than" operator.  Map will call `compare(a,b)` to see if "a < b" and then it will call `compare(b,a)` to see if `b < a`.  You keep trying to write a comparison function that checks "a = b" when all you need to write is one that returns "a < b".

Comment: yeah.. what was I thinking? Its so simple. Thanks a lot. Your code explains it best.

Comment: This is not a strict weak order, so has the same problem as Slava's answer.

Answer (score 10):

1. The comparator that is used in `std::map` must provide a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) of the objects.
2. Your comparator does not.
3. Therefore, your instance of `std::map` will produce undefined behavior.

*Note: It's generally easier to just have the comparator provide a **total ordering**.*

Additionally, let's describe what a strict weak ordering requires. Here, I'm taking excerpts from **C++ 2011, Section 25.4**.

- You're going to create a functor `Compator comp;` I'm going to refer to `comp(lhs, rhs)` as a function that returns a boolean. It's helpful to think of it as `lhs < rhs`.
- We're going to create a function `equiv(lhs, rhs)`. This is defined as `(!comp(lhs, rhs) && !comp(rhs, lhs))`. So, `!(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs)`.

We're required to have the following rules hold:

```
comp(a, b) && comp(b, c) implies comp(a, c)
equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c) implies equiv(a, c)
```

Comment: Also, `comp(a, b)` implies `!comp(b, a)`,  and `comp(a, a)` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you rewrite your comparator this way, it should work:

```
bool operator()(const int x, const int y) const {
    if(abs(x-y)<=minwidth) return false;
    else return x < y;
}
```

And you do not need to use find before inserting, you are doing double work. Just try to insert, if such key exists map will reject that insertion. `std::map::insert` also returns `std::pair<iterator,bool>` so you can check if insertion was successful or not.

Comment: Unfortuately, this operator does not provide a strict weak ordering.  Its particularly bad in that it will *seem* to work for most values being inserted into the map, but there are a few cases where the map will break badly.

Comment: @ChrisDodd can you give me an example when this will fail?

Comment: Insert two values that differ by slightly more than minwidth, then insert a value midway between those two values (within minwidth of both).  This will give you a map containing two values that compare equal by the comparator, and things will go downhill from there.  The details of the failure will depend on the internal implementation details of `std::map` in your library.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Consider minwidth = 100. I insert 100 first. then 201 which is not a problem. then if I insert 150,  then the comparator will check abs(100-150)<100? which is true so it would return false on both  the reflexive cases.So the map would assume 150~=100 and it will come out of the loop thinking it has found the element. It will not even encounter the next element 201. the same is true if 201 is encountered first. So what is the problem?

Comment: Assume a simple red-black tree.  Insert 100 first, then 201.  Now insert 150; it will replace 100 and you'll have 150 and 201 in the tree (two values within minwidth).  If that's not bad enough, now insert 225; it will replace 150, then insert 305; it will replace the 225.  Now search for 201 and it will fail to find it, as it will look in the wrong branch of the tree...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Why will it replace anything when I am finding using map::find before I insert? It would only wont it replace only if I insert it directly? when the std::find finds something it will never go inside the insert branch right?

Comment: It will replace any time you call insert with a value that compares as equal to an existing value (`operator()` returns false for both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`) whether you've previously called find is irrelevant.

Comment: @slava accepting brandon's answer because its simple and does exactly what I want.We were complicating things really bad

Comment: @ChrisDodd "it will replace any time you call insert with a value that compares as equal" may I see link to documentation that proves this behavior of the 'std::map'?

Comment: @VivekVK it is up to you, but Chris' examples does not seem to be correct.

Comment: @VivekVK: It depends on what you do in the `else` part.  As long as you never insert a value that compares as equal to an existing value in the map, you should be ok.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I'm stepping back to your example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689092/how-does-the-compare-function-in-stdmap-in-c-work-if-it-is-reflexively-true/24689122#comment38283750_24689166). Let's do the following: `map[100] = 10; map[101] = 15`. The end result is a map that has `map[100] == 15`, not `map[101] == 15`. So in your example, at the end, the map will have only 2 keys in it: `{100, 201}`

Comment: So your `std::map` implementation is different.  Try inserting 101, then 100, then 201.  Your map will have just 101 and not 100 or 201.  But the underlying problem is if you use a comparison function that is not weak order, the results will be undefined, so anything might happen

Comment: @ChrisDodd you cannot insert a key that compares as equal into map, unless it is a multimap. With multimap this comparator will be ambiguous, for regular map it should be ok.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "Try inserting 101, then 100, then 201. Your map will have just 101 and not 100 or 201." This is expected behaviour by OP.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I agree with inserting `101`, then `100`, then `201`, will cause the map to have only `101`. [Above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689092/how-does-the-compare-function-in-stdmap-in-c-work-if-it-is-reflexively-true/24689122#comment38283750_24689166), you claimed that inserting `100`, then `201`, then `150` would result in a map containing `{150, 201}`. However, that's not what would result. You'd result with a map containing `{100, 201}`. Additionally, I'm not talking about an implementation, I'm talking about the standard's requirements for the object.

Comment: @sharth: For some implementations of `std::map` that is what might happen.  The standard does not specify whether a newly inserted key that compares equal to an old key replaces it or not.  It might depend on whether you use `std::map::insert` or `std::map::operator[]` to insert new values.  The standard just says its undefined behavior, so anything might happen

Comment: @ChrisDodd The standard is __explicit__ about this behavior. For `std::map::operator[]`. Section 23.4.4.3 Paragraph 1: _"Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, T()) into the map."_ So we won't overwrite the key there. And for `std::map::insert`, we'll excerpt from Table 102. _"Inserts t if and only if there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of t."_