# How does std::map use a custom compare function in C++ (or how often is it called)?

Tags: c++11

I was trying to write some code for lexicographical sort and came across this sample code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::transform;
using std::map;
using std::cout;

struct Compare {
    bool operator() (const int& s0, const int& s1) const {
        cout << "in compare: s0=" << s0 << " s1=" << s1 << "\n";

        return s0 < s1;
    }
};

typedef map<int, int, Compare> num_count;

int main(){
   num_count nc;
   auto nums = { 4, 2, 5, 1, 6 };

    for (auto num : nums) {
        cout << "num=>" << num << '\n';
        nc[num]++;
    }

    for(auto elem : nc)
        cout << elem.first << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[link to wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BMVmVTye6se69Bfo)

The code works pretty much how I want it to work. I am just trying to understand the compare function. On first insert no comparison is one (obviously). On 2nd insert the compare function is called three times. This is the part that I don't understand. The closest I have come to understand this is that it is due to the way map is implemented (red-black tree). One of the link that gave some explanation was a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689092/how-does-the-compare-function-in-stdmap-in-c-work-if-it-is-reflexively-true).

Could someone please explain this in detail? Thanks.

Comment: So is your question actually "How often does std::map call compare?" If that's the case could you please simplify your example (e.g. use plain integers rather than some complex string format)?

Comment: Are you testing a debug build, by any chance? Some implementations in a debug build perform additional, unnecessary comparisons in order to weed out incorrect comparison functions. E.g. they could call `compare(a, b)` and then, even if the first call returns `true` (which should be sufficient), would call `compare(b, a)` anyway to confirm that the function properly returns `false`.

Comment: @Martin yes I think that would be a better question. I have added a link to wandbox and simplified the example as you suggested.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't think so, please see the link to wandbox, but let me know if you notice anything like that in the link. I went back to a book on STL, still didn't find any possible explanation.